# Access 2007 SQL SUM() is adding negative dollar amount in query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

When I'm running a query to give me a sum of the dollar amount the negative dollar amount is getting added to the total sum.  However, when I just use the total sum funtion in Access it gives me the correct sum.

```
SELECT SUM(VstoreTotal) AS NetSales
FROM [Store Reactive Matches All Cust]
WHERE VstoreTotal>0;

Ex. $250.00
    $100.00
    $0.00
    ($100.00)
```

Gives me $450.00

However, when I just use the total sum funtion in Access it gives me the correct sum.
Gives me $350.00

Comment: What is the *total sum funtion in Access*?

Comment: It makes no sense. You filter for `VstoreTotal > 0`, then no values returned can be negative. So remove the formatting and study the real values.

Comment: I'm speaking of the sum total (symbol: ∑).

Comment: I gave the formatting of the values as currency.  Yes it doesn't make sense.